# Uploading screenshots error to the developer console

Tags: android, screenshot, image-uploading, publishing

I get the following error when trying to upload an image as a screenshot to my developer console:

"You need to check that your screenshot image is a valid image."

1. I took a screenshot from my cell and uploaded it as a screenshot to the developer console and it worked.
2. Then I just added a line on top of the image using paint.
3. Tried to upload the modified image to the developer console but it failed.

My images are480wx800h PNG formatted images so it should be okay. (both the original and the modified bitmap).

Could any1 tell me how to solve this?
I want to upload a sample image from my app and add some instructions written on top of the image. 
But i can't do it.

Comment: PNG with right size must be OK. Maybe you save image in some other format after editing ?. This happened with normal images too, Just deleted all screenshots and re-upload them, it worked after that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved:

apparently when you save a PNG using paint it changes the bit depth to 32 instead of 24 and it adds transparency to the image which is forbidden by the Google play rules. So saving it as JPEG solved the problem

Answer (score 7):

[image: Max aspect ratio error]

It gave me error when i tried to upload IDE generated screen shot of **wrong aspect ratio**

i.e, i have taken Pixel screen shot from Android Studio IDE, and tried to upload directly to Playstore Store listing , it gave me error because the screen shot dimensions were of 1226 X **2502**, It began to upload when i changed them to 1226 X **2452** (aspect ratio 1:2)

I hope Android Studio IDE will fix this in future.

Answer (score 1):

for whomever may come across this answer. The issue in my case was that my screenshot resolution was too high at 6000px x 3000px.

so google play console couldn't process it, and instead presented me with the error message:

> "You need to check that your screenshot image is a valid image."

to fix it I scaled down the image to 2000 x 1000 pixels

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem every time I take screenshots from my phone, I resolved it by modifying the image resolution, to be specific by **minimizing** the height image. From 1080x**2220** to 1080x**2160**.

Clear explanation:

**2:1** aspect ratio is twice as wide as it is tall. This is why you need to resize your screenshot,.

I calculated the good resolution via this [website](https://calculateaspectratio.com/):
Just put your image **width** in 'Pixel Width' input and the height will be automatically calculated :)

[image]

### More explanation about Dimensions and aspect ratios:

[So, let’s say you have an image measuring 1920 pixels in width by 1080 pixels in height (that size equates to a Full HD image), and you had to crop it to fit a 2:1 space: you could simply leave the width intact, and crop the height down to exactly half, at 960 pixels.](https://thenextweb.com/basics/2019/02/12/how-to-crop-your-images-to-a-specific-size-or-aspect-ratio/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried uploading with classic Play Console and it worked. 
[image: Classic console]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had blocked the third-party cookies and the Play console just showed a generic error suggesting to retry